# How to loop through whole data which is located on backend

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm getting the correct response. And I'm trying to reach specific ID of data which is retrieved from another service. And thus retrieve all the data contained under that `ID`. Is there any logic how to do it?

So I tried this way (using method `findById` from mongoose) but doesn't work for me:

```
app.get('/add-to-cart/:id', async (req, res) => {
    let id = req.params.id;
    let cart = new Cart(req.body.cart ? req.body.cart : {});
  
    const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:4200/products');
    console.log(response);

    response.findById( id ).toArray();

});
```

Here is the output of the `console.log(response)` part:
[image]

Comment: Could you show the output of the `console.log(response)` statement?

Comment: Sure, I updated my question with a picture of an output in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to find the ID from the response object itself. The response object has all kind of data related to the HTTP request response, but most of that is irrelevant to you.

The actual data that comes in the response is within the 'data' property of the response.

So simply access that data variable, for example by destructuring it, and then use the native find function of arrays:

```
const { data } = await axios.get('http://localhost:4200/products');
return data.find((product) => product._id === id)
```

Note that you can't use the Mongoose's findById function here. That is a function related to the database, but you're not interacting with the database here, even though the HTTP request to get the products you want internally gets them from some database related to the other service.

Comment: Thanks alot, exactly the thing I wanted! I though that function `find()` works only with collection of database, I didn't know it also works with data which is read from the API.

Comment: Yeah Mongoose also has a `find` function for database collections, but it's different than the native function for arrays. You can read more about the native array functions for example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Arrays have a lot of very useful functions, such as `map`, `filter` (that some other posters suggested, but that returns another array instead of only one object), `reduce` and `forEach`. Those are some of the most used ones.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are looking for a specific ID in an array (`data`) of products you need to filter out the data in your response from `/products`.

```
app.get('/add-to-cart/:id', async (req, res) => {
    let id = req.params.id;
    let cart = new Cart(req.body.cart ? req.body.cart : {});
  

    const { data } = await axios.get('http://localhost:4200/products')

    const productId = data.find(el => el._id === id);

    response.findById(productId)

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with the following code:

```
const element = response.data.filter(e => e.id == <your_id>);
```

Comment: That's the thing I needed, but the problem is when I check it with `console.log(element)` I'm getting an empty array.

Comment: I want to retrieve all the data that is located under that specific id, how to do it better more precisely?